# Any WinRT iCommand/CommandBinding implementaiton samples out there?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

Abstracting commands into the View Model is a valuable practice with XAML/MVVM projects. I get that. And, I see ICommand in in WinRT; but, how do we implement it? I haven't found a sample that actually works. Anyone know?

Comment: you should grow some patience!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My all time favorite has to be the DelegateCommand provided by the Microsoft Patterns and Practices team. It allows you to create a typed command:

```cs
MyCommand = new DelegateCommand<MyEntity>(OnExecute);
...
private void OnExecute(MyEntity entity)
{...}
```

It also provides a way to raise the CanExecuteChanged event (to disable/enable the command)

```cs
MyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

Here's the code:

```cs
public class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecuteMethod;
    private readonly Action<T> _executeMethod;

    #region Constructors

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod)
        : this(executeMethod, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        _executeMethod = executeMethod;
        _canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            return CanExecute((T)parameter);
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Execute((T)parameter);
    }

    #endregion ICommand Members

    #region Public Methods

    public bool CanExecute(T parameter)
    {
        return ((_canExecuteMethod == null) || _canExecuteMethod(parameter));
    }

    public void Execute(T parameter)
    {
        if (_executeMethod != null)
        {
            _executeMethod(parameter);
        }
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        OnCanExecuteChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #endregion Public Methods

    #region Protected Methods

    protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    #endregion Protected Methods
}
```

Comment: I don't like the generic part (as default) but I like the sample!

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT - why don't you "[not] like the generic part"? If you want to avoid the generic, you'd have to make the code more complicated by taking Action<object>, or Action<dynamic> and then performing all of the associated casting and type checking to get the same result

Comment: @Shawn Kendrot - in ICommand.CanExecute, you could replace that potentially expensive try... catch block, couldn't you just do `return CanExecute(parameter as T)`, then in `CanExecute`, add a check for `parameter == null`?

Comment: nvm, forgot that you can't guarantee that `T` is a ref type

Comment: You could also check the type with an implicit cast. The code makes an assumption that you will pass in the appropriate type b/c you know your Command and what it expects.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [RelayCommand](https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/blob/master/src/MyToolkit/Command/RelayCommand.cs) class (only METRO code). The `NotifyPropertyChanged` class can be found [here](https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/blob/master/src/MyToolkit/Model/ObservableObject.cs). The `NotifyPropertyChanged` class is only used to allow bindings on `CanExecute` and update it with `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`.

The original relay command class can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a native class that implements it for you. The interface is not overly complicated if you want to implement it yourself, and the popular **MVVM Lite** toolkit includes its own version of **RelayCommand**. You can add MVVM Lite to your project by right-clicking on References and choosing "Manage NuGet Packages". If you don't have this option, enable Nuget under **Tools -> Extensions and Updates**.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a minimal end-to-end implementation of a XAML-MVVM command, and not found it yet.

So, following #Rico's answer I ended up with the following as a minimal RelayCommand which works. I use a similar minimal version in a large project.

```C#
public class RelayCommand : System.Windows.Input.ICommand {

    readonly Action<object> execute; 

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) {
        this.execute = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter) {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

The larger RelayCommand class seems to provide more control over `CanExecute` and `CanExecuteChanged`, but you don't need that to get started - and you may not need it at all.

To use it in a view model:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    << ... snip VM properties and notifications ...>>

    public RelayCommand DoSomethingCommand {
        get {
            return new RelayCommand(param => {
                this.DoSomething(param as AType);
                Debug.WriteLine("Command Executed");
            });
        }

    }
}
```

(We don't need the INotifyPropertyChanged for the Command, but any view model typically implements it.)

Finally, the XAML...

```XML
   <Grid>
        <!-- Set the data context here, for illustration. -->
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:ViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <!-- A sample control bind to a property -->
        <TextBlock 
             Text="{Binding AProp}"/>
        <!-- Bind a command -->
        <Button Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" CommandParameter="foo">Change!</Button>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this really good example at
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Working-with-ICommand-690ba1d4

```
<Page.Resources> 
        <local:MyCommandsCollection x:Key="MyCommands" /> 
</Page.Resources> 

   <Button Width="280" 
            Height="59" 
            Margin="513,280,0,0" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Command="{Binding MyFirstCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding Text, 
                                       ElementName=myTextBox}" 
            Content="Execute Command" /> 


public class MyCommandsCollection 
{ 
    public MyCommand MyFirstCommand 
    { 
        get { return new MyCommand(); } 
    } 
} 

public class MyCommand : ICommand 
    { 
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) 
        { 
            return true; 
        } 

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged; 

        public async void Execute(object parameter) 
        { 
            MessageDialog message = new MessageDialog( 
                "The command is executing, the value of the TextBox is " + parameter as String); 
            await message.ShowAsync(); 
        } 
    }
```

I tried this out with x:Bind and it works nicely. All I need is to expose a property in my ViewModel that returns a new Instance of the "MyCommand" class and it's all good.

Since I'm setting the DataContext in my XAML, I didn't need to mess with any of the "MyCommandCollection" stuff. Yay compiled binding.