# Context menu sender

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

So I have a context menu that appears when a user taps and holds on a listbox item. I have this code to get the value from the item that was tapped.

```
ListBoxItem contextMenuListItem = (ListBoxItem)(myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(((MenuItem)sender).DataContext));


string item = (contextMenuListItem).Content.ToString();
```

But the variable "item" now contains the value from the item that was tapped. I want to get the index from the item. Is it possible? And if yes, how?

I am using the context menu from Silverlight's toolkit.

Comment: Why do you need the index? what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I have a list of names and I want to remove the specific name from the list. I can search the list with a loop and get the index of the item and then remove it from the list, but sometimes two different people have the same name. So, if I use a loop, it will find the first person with that name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make context menu work for windows phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166876/how-to-make-context-menu-work-for-windows-phone)

Comment: nope, it doesnt answer my question

Comment: The answer to is use MVVM, use commanding and remove the specific item from the collection that the ListBox binds to. There is no need to loop through items to find something

Comment: @ShawnKendrot can you be a little more specific? show me some code on how to do that?

Comment: i've done some research about mvvm. it seems a little hard for me to do right now. isnt there any other way of doing what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my first Windows Phone app (last year) I did something like you and I used MVVM like Shawn Kendrot proposed.

My code is on GitHub. Feel free to have a look even if it's not an extraordinary application/code.

https://github.com/fabmoll/SimpleTodo

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to remove an item from a list with `ToString`? Here's what you do: Use an `ObservableCollection<`*`ModelItem`*`>`, bind that to the ListBox, and use [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413.aspx) on the `((MenuItem)sender).DataContext`. Binding a list of plain strings is a bad bad bad idea.

Better yet, take Shawn Kendrot's suggestion and do things in the MVVM way. Sure it may *seem* complicated to you right now, but it's pretty easy to wrap your head around with a little bit of work. I've been able to educate mere non-programming mortals on it; if you can code you should be able to learn how to work with the MVVM model.

Comment: I will try and do it with the MVVM way. Everyone says it's the best way to do it for the  thing I'm trying to do. Anyway, thanks for the answer!