# Context menu for List in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, contextmenu, menuitem-selection

First of all, I know about this topic: [How to make context menu work for windows phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166876/how-to-make-context-menu-work-for-windows-phone)

But this way is SOO complicated... 
So I have this XAML code:

```
 <StackPanel Name="friendsGrid" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent"> 
   <ListBox Name="friendsListBox" FontSize="32" Tap="friendsListBox_Tap">
     <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
     <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="MyContextMenu" Opened="MyContextMenu_Opened">
     <toolkit:MenuItem Header="action" Click="contextMenuAction_Click"/>
     </toolkit:ContextMenu>
     </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
   </ListBox>
 </StackPanel>
```

And I'm filling the list like this:

```
this.friendsListBox.Items.Add(friend.serviceName);
```

But, of course, when I do longtap, the context menu appears and selects the whole List, not only one item.

Is there some easy way to recognize the item was tapped?
Thanks

BTW, I found this method, but contextMenuListItem doesn't recieve anything, it's still null:

```
ListBoxItem contextMenuListItem = friendsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as ContextMenu).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;
```

Comment: can you show us your listbox itemtemplate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should put ContextMenu block into your ItemTemplate (not ListBox block).
Here short sample.
XAML:

```
            <ListBox Name="TestList" Margin="26,0,26,0" Height="380" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu" >
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Edit" Header="Edit" Click="Edit_Click"/>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Delete"  Header="Delete" Click="Delete_Click"/>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Code:

```
    public List<string> Items = new List<string>
    {
        "Item1",
        "Item2",
        "Item3",
        "Item4",
        "Item5",
    };

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TestList.ItemsSource = Items;
    }

    private void Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TestList.ItemContainerGenerator == null) return;
        var selectedListBoxItem = TestList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(((MenuItem) sender).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;
        if (selectedListBoxItem == null) return;
        var selectedIndex = TestList.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(selectedListBoxItem);
        MessageBox.Show(Items[selectedIndex]);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The questioner hasn't even upvoted the solution to his problem... lame.