# How to place a ContextMenu in a ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, contextmenu

I am trying to place a ContextMenu within the DataTemplate of my ListBox. The ListBox is placed within a PivotItem. For some reason, the ContextMenu does not show up with an item in the ListBox is pressed. I am unsure of the error since nothing shows in the Error List or while debugging.

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property ="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="brd"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <Image x:Name="recentImage" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="12" Width="115"/>                                
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<phone:PivotItem Header="recent">
            <ListBox x:Name="Recent" ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}" Margin="8" 
                     SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="imgListContextMenu">
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="share" Tap="shareContextMenuItem_Tap"/>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="favorite" Tap="favoriteContextMenuItem_Tap"/>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="set as start screen" Tap="setAsStartScreenContextMenuItem_Tap"/>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="delete" Tap="deleteContextMenuItem_Tap"/>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
         </phone:PivotItem>
```

Also, is Tap the best event handler method to use within each of the ContextMenu item?

Comment: Are you trying to have a contextmenu for each item within the ListBox, or for the ListBox as a whole?

Comment: For each item within the ListBox. So for instance, a user may be able to press on an item, and then perform some ContextMenu action on that item.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make context menu work for windows phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166876/how-to-make-context-menu-work-for-windows-phone)

Comment: I forgot to mention before, I have set `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}"` within the ListBox tag, which is a reference to a style I have in `PhoneApplicationPage.Resources` to place a border around a selected item in the ListBox. I have edited my question above to reflect this. I believe this is effecting the ContextMenu not being displayed, but I am not sure how?

Comment: This should not matter. But the main thing I notice is that your ItemTemplate for your listbox does not contain anything except the ContextMenu. I assumed this was an oversight in the question, and that you do actually show information to the user via a TextBlock or something. The ContextMenu will only show up when the user taps and holds the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my ListBox has its own custom style, I placed the contextmenu under where the image binding occurs.

Under the closing tag of VisualStateManager..

```
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <Image x:Name="recentImage" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="12" Width="115"/>                                
                        </Border>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="imgListContextMenu">
                                ...
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use

```
 <ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>...
 </ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Where exactly would I place that?

Comment: Also, `ListBox.ContextMenu` displays an error `The attachable property 'ContextMenu' was not found in type 'ListBox'` when attempting to place this directly below `<ListBox xName="Recent"... >`