# How to Add ContextMenu to Button

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, button, windows-phone-8, contextmenu

I have a StackPanel of a few buttons, which are themed to look like tiles. Each will have the ability to be pinned to the Start screen. I would like to add a ContextMenu to each to enable this functionality. How might I do this? Also, how do I determine the tapped item?

MainPage.xaml

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <Button x:Name="Tile1" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0" Click="1_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/1.png"/>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="Tile2" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0" Click="2_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/2.png"/>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="Tile3" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0" Click="3_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/3.png"/>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you created those Button's manually -I mean not [generated using DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166876/how-to-make-context-menu-work-for-windows-phone) or so-, you need to add ContextMenu for each of them manually too.

```
...
<Button x:Name="Tile1" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/IconicTileSmall.png"/>
    </Button.Content>
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Pin To Start" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</Button>
<Button x:Name="Tile2" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/IconicTileSmall.png"/>
    </Button.Content>
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Pin To Start" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</Button>
...
```

But at least, there is a way to reuse method that handle MenuItem's click event:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = (MenuItem) sender;
    var ctxMenu = (ContextMenu) menuItem.Parent;
    var tileButton = (Button) ctxMenu.Owner;

    //Next: pin corresponding tileButton to start
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually answered my next question too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780097/how-to-determine-contextmenu-tapped-item

Comment: yes a coincidence, I just read the next question after posting this one :-D