# How to Determine ContextMenu Tapped Item

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, button, windows-phone-8, contextmenu

I have a StackPanel that holds buttons, and I have added a `ContextMenu` so that each item may be pinned to the start screen by selecting that `MenuItem`. How might I determine on the `Tap` event which button has been selected?

MainPage.xaml

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button x:Name="Tile1" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0" Click="1_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/1.png"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="Tile2" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0" Click="2_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/2.png"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="Tile3" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0" Click="3_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/3.png"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
</StackPanel>
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="pin to start" Tap="ContextMenuItem_Tap"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

Edit**

Place the ContextMenu individually for each button.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button x:Name="Tile1" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0" Click="1_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/1.png"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="pin to start" Tap="ContextMenuItem_Tap"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="Tile2" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0" Click="2_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/2.png"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="pin to start" Tap="ContextMenuItem_Tap"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="Tile3" Height="173" Width="173" Margin="12,0,0,0" Click="3_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/3.png"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="pin to start" Tap="ContextMenuItem_Tap"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? what do you want here?

Comment: My original question was how to determine the item from the ContextMenu Tap event. All the buttons are assigned the same Tap event handler. With the help of another question, I got the solution below which I added as the answer. Everything works correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = (MenuItem) sender;
    var ctxMenu = (ContextMenu) menuItem.Parent;
    var tileButton = (Button) ctxMenu.Owner;
}
```