# C# - Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, listbox, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

Using **Windows Phone 8**

So I've been playing around with `ObservableCollection` and `Listboxes` and binding them but I've never played around with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I hear that this will make a lot of things easier i.e. automatically detecting if the something in the `ObservableCollection` changes.

If its not too much to ask is it possible for someone to provide me with a simple code sample which has these functions:

- Add
- Delete

So basically Just **adding the items to the ObservableCollection** and a button to **delete the selected item from the ObservableCollection** and this will update the ObsevableCollection.

It's just that I've never understood how the `INotifyPropertyChanged` works. Online samples didn't seem to work for me and all I'm asking is a simple sample of that.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to add ObservableCollection.

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
 {
    public AddItems LoadItems = new AddItems();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox.DataContext = LoadItems;
    }

    public class Items
    {
        public string ItemTitle { get; set; }
        public string ItemBody { get; set; }
        public string FolderID { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddItems : ObservableCollection<Items>
    {
        public AddItems()
        {
            Add(new Items() { ItemTitle = "Book", ItemBody = "A simple Book.", FolderID = Count.ToString() });
            Add(new Items() { ItemTitle = "Paper", ItemBody = "Something to write on.", FolderID = Count.ToString() });
            Add(new Items() { ItemTitle = "Pen", ItemBody = "Something you use to write.", FolderID = Count.ToString() });
        }
    }

    private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Now if I want to delete items from the listbox how can I do that? I tried:

```
   LoadItems.Remove(listBox.SelectedItem);
```

But that didn't work. How can I delete a selected item and let the ObservableCollection automatically detect that change and do a refresh so it wont show that deleted item?

Thanks!

Comment: try this way : `LoadItems.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex)`

Comment: @har07 Since I'm using contextMenu (user has to tap and hold to bring up the contextMenu), I've got to click the ListBox item and then delete it. Is there a way so that i could just hold the ListBox item and then clicking delete will delete the item rather than clicking the listbox item and THEN deleting it?

Comment: yes that common scenario, and common mistake is people adding ContextMenu to ListBox instead of ListBoxItem. Check this references to achieve that : 1.[simpler way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14168934/2998271), 2.[more MVVM compliant way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14168934/2998271)

Comment: @har07 I just checked and seems that I have already added the ContextMenu to the ListBoxItem rather than the Listbox Itself but I'm a bit confused when it comes to reading the specific listbox Item Index can you please help me with that?

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20780070/2998271)

Answer (score 4):

`ObservableCollection<T>` already implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which makes it notify UI whenever item added or removed from collection. So, for example, along with data-binding, simply calling `ObservableCollection<T>.Add()` function is sufficient to add item to collection as well as notify UI to display newly added item without further effort.

[INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a different thing. It is used to notify UI to update displayed value when value of underlying property has changed.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `INotifyPropertyChanged` to handle `Add`/`Remove` methods: `ObservableCollection<T>` will handle these for you.

You need `INotifyPropertyChanged` when you need the screen to update when item which is already in the collection changes, e.g. one of it's properties gets different value.

To make that happen `T` has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, not the `ObservableCollectinon` itself.